# Lower bound of log(1-x)

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

I've been thinking about this problem for several weeks, and I can't seem to come to an answer. I've tried using Taylor's Series with Taylor's Remainder Theorem, but I've hit a dead end in that direction. I've been told the lower bound is $$-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-...-\frac{x^k}{k}-\frac{x^k}{k} \leq log(1-x) \leq -x-\frac{x^2}{2}-...-\frac{x^k}{k}$$ where the bounds of x are $0  \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Does anyone have a clue how to prove this?

Comment: What is $k$? is the last term in the LHS a mistake?

Comment: The inequality you propose should be reversed. See this [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BLog%5B1+-+x%5D,+-x+-+x%5E2%2F2%7D,+%7Bx,+0,0.5%7D%5D) where I use the partial expension $-x - x^2/2$.

Comment: @nbubis The last term in the LHS was not a mistake. Let me edit and show the RHS for clarification.

Comment: @Zubzub you are correct to say $-x- \frac{x^2}{2}$ should be reversed. However, on the RHS, it would be $-x- \frac{2x^2}{2}$, which would not be reversed.

Comment: ^ I meant LHS. Oops. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BLog%5B1+-+x%5D,+-x+-+x%5E2%7D,+%7Bx,+0,0.5%7D%5D) is what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\log(1-x)+x+x^2\right) = 1+2x-\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{x(1-2x)}{1-x} $$
now the above is a non-negative function on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, hence 
$$-x-x^2 \le \log(1-x) \le -x, \quad x \in [0,1/2].$$

Comment: This is good. Out of curiosity, is there a way to prove the lower bound without knowing $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ are the bounds of $x$, and to prove the bounds along the way?

Comment: Never mind! I used similar logic as you and figured out my own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\log(1-x)$ for $x \in I:=[0, \frac{1}{2}]$. For $x \in I$ we have

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}<0$, hence $f$ is decreasing on $I$. Therefore

$- \log 2=f(1/2) \le f(x) \le f(0)=0$ for all $x \in I$.