# How to prove the 2nd question of sequence and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

$$a_1 = \frac32\quad\text{and}\quad\forall n \ge 2,\quad a_n = \frac{3na_{n-1}}{2a_{n - 1} +n - 1}.$$

1. Get $a_n$
2. Prove: $$\forall n \in\Bbb N,\quad a_1a_2\dots a_n < 2\cdot n!$$

Here is what I have gone so far:

$$a_n = \frac{n3^n}{3^n - 1}$$

But I do not know how to prove the question 2.

I found that it is equivalent to proving:

$$
\left(1-\frac13\right)\left(1-\frac1{3^2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac1{3^n}\right)> \frac12.
$$

Comment: It doesn't even correspond to your value for $a_1.$

Comment: I think $a_1=\frac{3}{2}$ to make your explicit formula for $a_n$ correct

Comment: The exercise seems to have something wrong, the general term $a_n$ does not seem bounded by $1$ in general.

Comment: @Ilovemath Why should it?

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time that I use the MathLex to input the problem, the problem is wrong, will revise it.@AnneBauval

Comment: Sorry, the answer is correct, it is wrong due to I input wrongly the question. Yes, you are absolutely right, thanks for pointing it out. @Faoler

Comment: MathJax, not MathLex

Comment: @FrancisBacon but if $a_1=\frac{3}{2}$ then the second question must be $a_1a_2...a_n>2n!$

Comment: @Faoler May I know why? Double-check that, guess you may be wrong.

Comment: @FrancisBacon the product will be $\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k 3^k}{3^k-1}=n! \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{3^k-1} \right)>n!$  ..and yes sorry for that I forgot that it's $2n!$ not $n!$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fun problem. Apparently $\prod_i(1-p_i) \geq 1 - \sum_ip_i$ with $p_i \in [0,1]$ is always true. But how to demonstrate it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013663/fun-problem-apparently-prod-i1-p-i-geq-1-sum-ip-i-with-p-i-in-0-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) takes two forms:
$$\phi(q):=\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-q^k)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^kq^{(3k^2-k)/2},\quad\text{for }|q|<1.$$
The second one provides the desired lower bound:
$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{3^k}\right)&>\phi\left(\frac13\right)\\&>\sum_{k=-1}^1\frac{(-1)^k}{3^{(3k^2-k)/2}}\\&=-\frac1{3^2}+1-\frac13\\&=\frac59\\&>\frac12.
\end{align}$$

A more elementary method is to use [a lower bound for $\ln:$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2663217)
$$\forall x\in[0,1/2]\quad\ln(1-x)\ge-x-x^2$$
$$\begin{align}\ln\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{3^k}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(1-\frac1{3^k}\right)\\&\ge\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(-\frac1{3^k}-\frac1{3^{2k}}\right)\\&=-\frac12-\frac18=-\frac58
\end{align}$$
and $e^{-5/8}>0.53.$

Comment: Sorry, the answer is correct, it is wrong due to I input wrongly the question.

Comment: Could you update your answer?

Comment: awesome!! It is really elegant. Let me find some materials to know what the Euler function is. Guess the Euler function is the math in Math major at college.

BTW, could you resolve it with the knowledge of high school math?

Answer (score 3):

Using $(1 - x)(1 - y) = 1 - x - y + xy > 1 - x - y$ for all $x, y > 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(1-\frac13\right)\left(1-\frac1{3^2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac1{3^n}\right)\\[6pt]
 >{}& \left(1 - \frac13 - \frac{1}{3^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{3^3}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{3^n}\right)\\[6pt]
 >{}& \left(1 - \frac13 - \frac{1}{3^2} - \frac{1}{3^3}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{3^4}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{3^n}\right)\\[6pt]
 >{}& \cdots\\
 >{}& 1 - \frac13 - \frac{1}{3^2}- \frac{1}{3^3} - \cdots - \frac{1}{3^n}\\[6pt]
={}& \frac12 + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3^n}\\
 >{}& \frac12.
\end{align*}